# JavaScript: how to loop by adding the values of variables with 1, 2, 3, ... at the end?

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm a beginning JavaScript user. I'd like to calculate a score of 15 questions from a program.
What I need:
I put the value I received to JSq1, JSq2, etc. then I add them up and divided by total question and round up a score. I can lay everything in many lines but that does not look efficient. I'm trying to figure out a way to use loop to get all the same result.

Please help.

THANKS

```
<script language = "JavaScript">
// the following may work
var JSq1 =Varq1score.getValue();
var JSq2 =Varq2score.getValue();
var JSq3 =Varq3score.getValue();
var JSq4 =Varq4score.getValue();
var JSq5 =Varq5score.getValue();
var JSq6 =Varq6score.getValue();
var JSq7 =Varq7score.getValue();
var JSq8 =Varq8score.getValue();
var JSq9 =Varq9score.getValue();
var JSq10 =Varq10score.getValue();
var JSq11 =Varq11score.getValue();
var JSq12 =Varq12score.getValue();
var JSq13 =Varq13score.getValue();
var JSq14 =Varq14score.getValue();
var JSq15 =Varq15score.getValue();
var totalScore = JSq1 + JSq2 + JSq3 + ...
var totalQuestion = 15
var finalScore = parseFloat(totalScore/totalQuestion*100).toFixed(0);

// I'd like to do the following but don't know how to specify JSq1, JSq2, etc in a loop so I don't have to repeat the lines so many times.
var totalQ = 15;
for (i = 0; i <= totalQ ; i++) {
  var JSq+[i] = "Varq"+ i + "score.getValue()";
}


for (i = 0; i <= totalQ ; i++) {
  var totalScore = totalScore + JSq + [i];
}

...
</script>
```

Comment: Where do the `Varq1score`, etc variables come from?

Comment: The answer you're asking for is simple (`window["Varq"+ i + "score"].getValue()`, since global variables are properties of the `window` Object), but don't do this. That would still be _dirty_. Please post more code so we can help you write it in a better/simpler way

Answer (score -1):

1) Build an object `all_vars` with all the variable. (Here with object shorthand property, `{ JSq1 }` will be equivalent to `{ JSq1: Varq1score.getValue() }`

2) Use `Object.values` to get values of above object in an array.

3) Use any loop (in this case we are using reduce) to build total score dynamically.

With these slight changes to your current code, you can achieve the result. Check the following sample code.

```js
var JSq1 = 3;
var JSq2 = 3;
var JSq3 = 3;
var JSq4 = 3;
var JSq5 = 3;
var JSq6 = 3;
var JSq7 = 3;
var JSq8 = 3;
var JSq9 = 3;
var JSq10 = 3;
var JSq11 = 3;
var JSq12 = 3;
var JSq13 = 3;
var JSq14 = 3;
var JSq15 = 3;

var all_vars = {
  JSq1,
  JSq2,
  JSq3,
  JSq4,
  JSq5,
  JSq6,
  JSq7,
  JSq8,
  JSq9,
  JSq10,
  JSq11,
  JSq12,
  JSq13,
  JSq14,
  JSq15
};
var totalScore = Object.values(all_vars).reduce((sum, jsq) => sum + jsq, 0);
var totalQuestion = 15;
var finalScore = parseFloat((totalScore / totalQuestion) * 100).toFixed(0);

console.log(finalScore)
```